# Publishing ASP.NET Core 2 Angular 6 SPA Template Application

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, deployment, publish

I'm developing an application in DotNet core 2.1, which contains an angular template. I finished the demo and I want to switch to the production mode, so that I can upload the files to azure. Before I upload files to a server, I would like to run the site in local, to make sure everything works properly. 
The file structure is as follows:

[image].

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@balramchavan/deploy-angular-asp-net-51021afd5ab3, but it didn't help much.
After executing the command from the tutorial I have the following structure in the release folder:

[image: folder]

In Client app we have disc folder, and inside the following files:

[image: files]

I tried to run the application at the local site using the command **dotnet AppServerPortal.dll** 
However, I get the following error:

[image: error].

If someone knows what the problem is, I'd like to get a step by step solution to the problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: *Did* you install npm?

Comment: Of course I am.

Comment: And yet the error complains about the PATH. How did you add it? Trhough the VS installer or independently? I remember running into something similar a while ago because the Node, npm versions included with VS were too old

Comment: Path is not problem. I figured out what the problem is. I am writing a response to the post soon.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the next steps:

```
1. Open ClientApp folder and run CMD
2. ng build --prod
3. npm i -g http-server --save
4. http-server ./dist
```

If your application is running, but certain parts of the application do not work, as it did in my case, do the following:
Change the configuration of the anular inside angular.json
Put this piece of code and everything will work properly:

```
"configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization":true,
                                           "outputHashing":"none",
                                           "sourceMap":false,
                                           "extractCss":false,
                                           "namedChunks":false,
                                           "aot":true,
                                           "extractLicenses":true,
                                           "vendorChunk":false,
                                           "buildOptimizer":false
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: "... Put inside angular.json" just at the bottom?  Right after schema? inside the array for "apps"?

Comment: File: angular.json
$schema / projects / architect / configurations

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to troubleshoot. I would recommend navigating to Azure portal selecting the App Service that you had created then selecting the "Console" option under the "Development Tools" then in the console that will be displayed to the right, should default to something like `D:\home\site\wwwroot` enter dotnet "nameOfYourDLL".dll and hit enter.

If you aren't sure, just enter `ls` to view all contents of the directory, and then locate the dll name.

This will try to run your application in Azure, often times if something is broken you will get very valuable logs. In the past it has always pointed me to the right place, rather if it was a connection string issue or azure key vault issue, or database initializer etc.

Also you can read about how to deploy your angular and azure app in this [blog](https://medium.com/@omikolaj1/complete-guide-to-deploying-angular-and-asp-net-33a0976d0ec1)

[image]